# displaying ?? instead of the name of the lstlisting when using \cref

Tags: listings, cleveref

I change the name of the label of the `lstlisting` to Algorithm and it works fine for the caption. But when I use `\cref`, the instead of displaying algorithms 1 it shows ?? 1.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
\begin{document}

\cref{example}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor, caption=A caption, label={example}]
%My listing
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I already tried `\crefname{listing}{algorithm}{algorithms}` but it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `cleveref` is one of the packages that should be loaded last, even **after** `hyperref`, since it does a lot of redefinitions on counters and labelling/referring (of course, since this is the topic `cleveref` is about).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}


\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
\crefname{listing}{algorithm}{algorithms}

\begin{document}

\cref{example}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor, caption=A caption, label={example}]
%My listing
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You just change the place where you put `\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}` ? That's it ?

Comment: @PierrickBersier: Yes, that's it ;-) I will add a screen shot in a few moments

Comment: now it displays listing 1, how can I make it display algorithm 1 ?

Comment: sorry I missed a line.

Comment: @PierrickBersier: Nope, It was my fault. I forgot the `\crefname` in my first edit.

Comment: Thanks it work like a charm ! Just need 2 reputation point more to give a +1 to your answer.

Comment: @PierrickBersier - I just up-voted your posting. You should be able to up-vote answers from now on. :-)

Comment: @PierrickBersier: I can't upvote your question twice ;-) Edit: Oh, just saw that Mico upvoted ;-)

Comment: I upvoted your answer too...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Dankeschön ! +1

Comment: @Mico: I suspected your evil-deeds ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`Cleveref`  has to be informed of the name you want to give to the environment. Here is a solution which uses the name of the environment dynamically (partially!). The code can be written in a `cleveref.cfg` file:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex,final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\crefname{lstlisting}{\MakeLowercase\lstlistingname}{\MakeLowercase\lstlistingname s}
\Crefname{lstlisting}{\lstlistingname}{\lstlistingname s}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithm}
\begin{document}

\cref{example}
\begin{lstlisting}[ caption=A caption, label={example}]%style=Matlab-editor,
%My listing
end
\end{lstlisting}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Pseudo-code}
\cref{example2}
\begin{lstlisting}[ caption=A caption, label={example2}]%style=Matlab-editor,
%My listing
end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]